# Is there a formula to get the number of regions of a plane bounded by lines, where two or more lines are parallel?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

[$A000124$](https://oeis.org/A000124), as described in the OEIS,

> Define a number of straight lines in the plane to be in general arrangement when (1) no two lines are parallel, (2) there is no point common to three lines. Then these are the maximal numbers of regions defined by n straight lines in general arrangement in the plane. - Peter C. Heinig

The numbers in the sequence are obtained using the formula $$\frac{n(n + 1)}{2} + 1\label{1}\tag{1}.$$

There are two conditions in the description. The first one is that no two lines are parallel. The second one is that there must be no common point to three lines.

Claim 1: For $n \geq 3$, if $p$ lines are parallel, then $p - 1$ regions are removed from \ref{1}.

I think I should start with the fact that two intersecting lines divides a plane into $4$ regions and making them parallel removes a region from the count. It seems as if I could prove this by induction. Can someone help me, or at least give me a hint?

Comment: What does '$p$ lines are parallel' mean exactly? Consider $n=p=4$ and the arrangements $\|\|$ and $\#$.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. I am referring to $k$ pairwise parallel lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a general result:

If we consider $n$ lines in the plane partitionned into $N$ classes of parallel lines with resp. "cardinalities" $C_1,\cdots, C_N$, they split the plane into:

$$R=\frac{1}{2}(n^2-s)+n+1 \ \ \text{regions,  where } s=\sum C_i^2 \tag{1}$$

(This nice formula can be employed of course with some of the $C_i$s equal to $1$). It is mentionned, written in a slightly different way in an answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/349802).

I have an intuitive understanding of this formula, but till know I haven't succeeded to establish it by recurrence.

[image]

*Fig. 1 : A case where $n=6, \ N=3$ with $C_1=1 \text{ (red lines)},$  $\ C_2=2 \text{ (blues lines)},$  $\ C_3=3 \text{ (black lines)}$, giving rise to $R=\frac12(6^2-14)+6+1=18$ regions.*

Remarks:

a) Of course, (1) is true under the classical assumption that no triple of lines are concurrent in a same point.

b) If for all $i$, we have $C_i=1$ (lines in general position), we get $s=n$, and retrieve the result you mention:

$$\frac{n(n + 1)}{2} + 1.$$

Comment: Is there a more general formula for three or more concurrent lines?

Comment: The fact that 3 lines are concurrent is equivalent to say that the triangle they were forming (that one can assume arbitrarily small WLOG) disappears ; therefore, there is a "minus one" in the global count.  With more than 3 lines, I don't know...